# Enthought Canopy iPython console fills with text and loses prompt

Tags: enthought

I'm running the latest academic distribution of the Canopy IDE on a Windows 7 machine. In the iPython console, if I ask for a docstring (for example, typing "linspace?"), the resulting text fills up the console and gets cut off at the top and bottom. Afterwards, there is no longer an "In [#]" prompt and I cannot type any further commands into the console. If I don't want to lose all of the variables I have defined during the session, I have found that I can open a new editor window (File/New Editor Window) and I will once again have an "In [last #]" prompt where I can enter commands. However, this is a rather a nuisance. I would like to be able to view docstrings without having to open a new window each time. Is there a way I can fix this?

For reference, I have Canopy version 1.0.1.1189.

Update: this only seems to happen when I use the question mark, not if I enter, for example, "help(linspace)." Maybe I should just stick to using help() instead of question marks?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't specific to Canopy and should apply to IPython in general. When you print a long docstring (i.e. one longer than your screen), it prints the output to something call a "pager" which allows you to scroll through the text. I think IPython (more or less) uses [`less`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29).

When you're in the pager, you can press the `q` key to exit (and return to the IPython prompt). (Also, space bar pages down, `b` pages up.)